# Indexing numpy array with bounds checking

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, array-broadcasting

Suppose I have some random numpy array:

```
>>> x = np.random.randn(10, 4, 4)
```

So this can be viewed as 10 4x4 arrays. Now, I also have some coordinates with respect to each of these arrays:

```
>>> coords.shape
(10, 4, 4, 2)
```

and a particular element of this array might look like the following:

```
>>> coords[i][j][k]
array([ 2,  2])
```

Now, I'd like to create an array, `y` of size `(10, 4, 4)`, where `y[i][j][k] = x[coords[i][j][k]]` if `coords[i][j][k]` is in bounds, and `0` otherwise.

I've tried doing something like the following:

```
>>> y = np.where(np.logical_and(
                 np.all(coords >= 0, axis = 3), 
                 np.all(coords <= 3, axis = 3)), 
                 x[tuple(coords)], 0)
```

But I can't quite get the broadcasting rules correct, and I'm getting errors.

For example, say we have,

```
>>> x = np.array([
                 [[1., 2.],
                  [4., 5.]],
                 [[6., 7.],
                  [8., 9.]]])
```

with,

```
>>> coords = np.array([
                       [[[0,-1], [0, 0]],
                        [[1, 1], [1, 0]]],
                       [[[1, 1], [1, 0]],
                        [[7, 2], [0, 0]]]
                      ])
```

Then, I'd somehow like to get

```
y = np.array([
             [[0., 1.],
              [5., 4.]],
             [[9., 8.],
              [0., 6.]]])
```

How can I achieve this in Python?

Comment: Won't `np.where(mask,x,0)` work where `mask` is the `all` mask? That is, you could have listed `x` instead of `x[tuple(coords)]` there?

Comment: So that just gives you `x`, except in those positions where the coords are out of bounds. Not `x` shuffled with respect to the new coordinates.

Comment: Didn't you mean [j][k] there at : `if coords[i][j][j] is in bounds, a`? Also, what shuffling are we talking about?

Comment: Edited to reflect your above comment. And `coords` can be thought of as a 'shuffle' of the elements, but some coordinates may occur twice, or not at all, so it may not be a true shuffle.

Comment: So, `coords[i,j,k,0]` is indexing into the second axis and `coords[i,j,k,1]` into the third axis of `x`?

Comment: @Divakar, not quite - I've given an example. See if that helps explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: That's not me. Appreciate the example. Upvoted for the addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bit of [`adavnced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) work was needed and should work for generic `n-dim` cases -

```
m,n = x.shape[0], x.shape[-1]
mask = (coords < n).all((-1)) & (coords >=0).all((-1))
v_coords = np.where(mask[:,:,:,None],coords,0)
out = x[np.arange(m)[:,None,None], v_coords[...,0], v_coords[...,1]]
out[~mask] = 0
```